# Why does iterating on this API output give me different data than the one in the json.dumps (json.loads)?

Tags: python, json, themoviedb-api

I'm iterating on a `json.loads` object that has all the info I need (`original_title`).
When I iterate on it I got incomplete result.
Where is my mistake? How can I improve this code to have complete result?

My code:

```
TMDB_TOKEN = "PUT YOURS HERE IF YOU WANNA TEST"
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization":  TMDB_TOKEN
    }
id = 17520
url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/{person_id}/movie_credits".format(person_id=id)
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,)
parsed = json.loads(response.text)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=1))
all_filmo = { "doc":[] , 'cinema': [] , "tv" : [] }
for i in parsed['cast']:
    print(i['original_title'])
```

You can see that there is A LOT of missing.

The `json.dumps`. I kept only the original title.

```
   "original_title": "Cin\u00e9ma par... C\u00e9dric Klapisch",
   "original_title": "Quand Jean devint Renoir",
   "original_title": "Toujours pas ... A bout de souffle",
   "original_title": "Babyphone",
   "original_title": "Un air de famille",
   "original_title": "In Transit",
   "original_title": "Belmondo l'influenceur",
   "original_title": "Les Poup\u00e9es russes",
   "original_title": "Peut-\u00eatre",
   "original_title": "Casse-T\u00eate Chinois",
   "original_title": "Ballerina",
   "original_title": "Belmondo, il \u00e9tait une fois le beau monde",
   "original_title": "L'Auberge espagnole",
   "original_title": "Ce qui nous lie",
   "original_title": "Le P\u00e9ril jeune",
   "original_title": "Le ramoneur des lilas",
   "original_title": "Babysitter",
   "original_title": "L'Auberge espagnole",
   "original_title": "Les Poup\u00e9es russes",
   "original_title": "Paris",
   "original_title": "Peut-\u00eatre",
   "original_title": "Ni pour, ni contre (bien au contraire)",
   "original_title": "Chacun cherche son chat",
   "original_title": "Le P\u00e9ril jeune",
   "original_title": "Un air de famille",
   "original_title": "Lumi\u00e8re et Compagnie",
   "original_title": "Riens du tout",
   "original_title": "Ma part du g\u00e2teau",
   "original_title": "Casse-T\u00eate Chinois",
   "original_title": "Ce qui me meut",
   "original_title": "In Transit",
   "original_title": "Ce qui nous lie",
   "original_title": "Le ramoneur des lilas",
   "original_title": "Deux moi",
   "original_title": "Aur\u00e9lie Dupont, l'espace d'un instant",
   "original_title": "En corps",
   "original_title": "Le Poisson rouge",
   "original_title": "La F\u00eate du Cin\u00e9ma",
   "original_title": "La Venue de l\u2019Avenir",
   "original_title": "Casse-T\u00eate Chinois",
   "original_title": "Paris",
   "original_title": "Ce qui nous lie",
   "original_title": "Les Confins du monde",
   "original_title": "Princesses",
   "original_title": "Deux moi",
   "original_title": "L'Auberge espagnole",
   "original_title": "Les Poup\u00e9es russes",
   "original_title": "Paris",
   "original_title": "Chacun cherche son chat",
   "original_title": "Peut-\u00eatre",
   "original_title": "Le P\u00e9ril jeune",
   "original_title": "Casse-T\u00eate Chinois",
   "original_title": "Ce qui me meut",
   "original_title": "Ni pour, ni contre (bien au contraire)",
   "original_title": "Ma part du g\u00e2teau",
   "original_title": "Un air de famille",
```

And my iteration result:

```
Cinéma par... Cédric Klapisch
Quand Jean devint Renoir
Toujours pas ... A bout de souffle
Babyphone
Un air de famille
In Transit
Belmondo l'influenceur
Les Poupées russes
Peut-être
Casse-Tête Chinois
Ballerina
Belmondo, il était une fois le beau monde
L'Auberge espagnole
Ce qui nous lie
Le Péril jeune
Le ramoneur des lilas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the [`response`](https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/person-movie-credits) is of format:

```
{
  cast: [{...original title}],
  crew: [{...original title}]
}
```

But the script is only iterating over `cast` key.